# Difference between File & AtomicFile

Tags: android

I need to implement atomic transactions of file because I need to that files where I am writting not to corrupt either the app stops or the user kills it. For this reason I rewied that atomicfile.

I done one test but check the differents between file and atomic file because the documentation Android said that atomic file created one backup file and use it that the operación writr failed. But I dont find that backup file and i dont know what It is different between two implements of the class.

Somebody could me what is it the different and is It the way for resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is it a problem that you cannot find that backup file? If all works you are done i would say.

Comment: Yes. I dont find the backup file. But the problem is not that. The problem is what I dont know what is the different between file and atomic file because when i closes the app or kill app the size of the both files is the same then I dont know what It is the differents between both implements...

Tha atomic file is the best way to solve that problem?

Comment: Why do you think that if you write five bytes to file that the result would be different for the two types? The resulting file will be the same. Which problem are you trying to solve? I thougth you would like to do atomic transactions. Now are you?

Comment: Ok. I understand you but my problem is that when i stop the app i will expect that the atomic file either will continue writing or what the both files will be bit different because I supposed that the atomic file would write the last block and would be quite different (some bites). But my surprise was what the files are equals...

Where is the different between those implementations? Will Be the file corrupt?

Comment: You still think that the difference is in the produced files? The difference is only in the way they are made and handled. The difference is in the possibility to handle atomic transactions. Not by the files. Files cannot handle anything but by the class AtomicFile.  Now for what do you need atomic transactions? Please give your user case.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. I want to atomic transactions because I don't want to my file will be corrupted when the user kill or destroyed the app. I want to do transactions atomics in the file because otherwise the file will be corrupted. I don't care if the file has been written completely because I have another backup file. Buy I will find one way of will write all file before that user will kill the app will be wonderfull. 

Do you know what is it the best way for this?